# How do I extract a value from XML using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to return just a single result from the following XML when you search by UID:

```
<Photos>
  <Photo UID="a3d508784ff3456da7bf2ff8ce08e577">
    <Date>2014-08-22T14:00:32.7958436+01:00</Date>
    <File>a3d508784ff3456da7bf2ff8ce08e577.jpg</File>
    <CrimeRef>CR123456/14</CrimeRef>
  </Photo>
  <Photo UID="735620a99f2c4dfd9f2c1870136e993e">
    <Date>2014-08-22T14:07:29.0364635+01:00</Date>
    <File>735620a99f2c4dfd9f2c1870136e993e.jpg</File>
    <CrimeRef>CR999999/99</CrimeRef>
  </Photo>
  <Photo UID="c186993e8a0246c29dd180396dfea47b">
    <Date>2014-08-22T14:07:29.6835282+01:00</Date>
    <File>c186993e8a0246c29dd180396dfea47b.jpg</File>
    <CrimeRef>CR999999/99</CrimeRef>
  </Photo>
</Photos>
```

I'm using the following code for this:

```
var fileList = xml.Descendants("Photo")
                  .Where(e => e.Attribute("UID") != null 
                         && (string)e.Attribute("UID").Value == ID)
                  .ToList();

var fileName = fileList[0];
```

The problem is that fileList[0] has the entire XML element, rather than just the file name:

[image]

Is there anyway to just do an equivalent of *'select File from'* in LINQ that will allow me to just return the 'File' value for that element? I've tried doing this with no luck:

```
var fileName = fileList[0]['File'];
```

Many thanks

Comment: Add `.Select(x=>(string)x.Element("File"))` after `Where`

Comment: Thank you so much LB! Please add as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add

```
.Select(x=>(string)x.Element("File"))
```

after `Where`

PS: Casting XElement to a type is safer since it wouldn't also throw exception even if File tag doesn't exists (just returns null)

Answer (score 2):

`Select()` the `File` node's `Value` property in your LINQ:

```
var fileList = xml.Descendants("Photo")
        .Where(e => e.Attribute("UID") != null && (string)e.Attribute("UID").Value == ID)
        .Select(n => n.Element("File").Value)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: this will return the element including xml tags not the value.